# How to enable regional AWS Security Token Service (STS) and be able to use AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli

After enabling the Middle East (Bahrain & UAE) regions.
when using the AWS CLI I received this error even though I've enabled STS in Regional endpoints.

[image: image1]

[image: image4]

Comment: Where/how are you passing the Security Token? Are you storing it in the `~/.aws/credentials` file? What is the configuration of your `shareprod` profile? Do you have it working with any _other_ regions?

Comment: yes, I'm passing in `~/.aws/credentials`, it's correctly configured. you can see that in the above picture using the same access with different global regions `us-east-1` worked.
I have enabled both Middle East (Bahrain & UAE) regions at the same time however currently it only work for UAE and this after more than 16 hours

Answer (score 2):

Might be relevant...

From [Managing AWS STS in an AWS Region - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_enable-regions.html):

> Session tokens from Regional AWS STS endpoints are valid in all AWS Regions. Session tokens from the global STS endpoint are valid **only in AWS Regions that are enabled by default**. If you intend to enable a new Region for your account, you can use session tokens from Regional STS endpoints. If you choose to use the global endpoint, you must **change the Region compatibility of STS session tokens** for the global endpoint. **Doing so ensures that tokens are valid in all AWS Regions.**
> ...
> In the **Change region compatibility of session tokens for global endpoint** dialog box, select **Valid in all AWS Regions**. Then choose Save changes.

Comment: Very helpful indeed.  I was already looking at that document but I missed this detail.  Thx

Answer (score 0):

it just worked, but it seems that might take 24 hours, I just posted here so if anyone faced this, just give it time.

Comment: using the AWS CLI is working, however, Terraform still gets the below error if the region is not from the global region.
``` │ Error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found.│ 
│ Error: failed to refresh cached credentials, operation error STS: AssumeRole, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: api error InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on provider.tf line 9, in provider "aws":
│    9: provider "aws" ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).